# React Native: pass onclick to tab

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` to create footer tab, like as below:

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
    UserScreen: UserScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarComponent: FooterTabs,
  },
);
```

and in `FooterTabs` on home screen button, i have this code:

```
if (this.props.navigation.state.index === 0) {
    // i want call scrollToUp function in HomeScreen component
}
```

i want when user is in HomeScreen and press on home button react call scrollToUp method in HomeScreen.

===== resolved:
I added this code to HomeScreen:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.navigation.setParams({
      onFocus: this.scrollToUp,
   });
}
```

and edit `FooterTabs` like as below:

```
if (this.props.navigation.state.index === 0) {
   this.props.navigation.state.routes[0].params.onFocus();
}
```

Comment: DId you try using react-navigations ScrollView? `import { ScrollView } from "react-navigation"`

Comment: Try reading https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/scrollables.html#docsNav

Answer (score 2):

Hav you trid putting your Homescreen in a scrollView , and when the user presses home button ,

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {

render(){
return(

< ScrollView ref={(ref) => { this.scrollListReftop = ref; }}>
// your code here    
 < /ScrollView>
)
}

}
```

// add this to scroll to the top of scrollView inside your componentDidMount of Homescreen

```
componentDidMount(){
setTimeout(() =>this.scrollListReftop.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true}),10);
}
```

Hope its clear, feel free for any doubts.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want scroll to top when component mounted, i want when user double click on footer, scrollView scrolling to top

Comment: what you can do is onPress of that tab , call any function suppose homePressed is the name, and then execute that statement for scrollingToTop

Comment: i have a function called scrollToUp, i want when user double click in home button my function called

Comment: does react navigation expose doubletap on tabbar buttons? i dont think thats a feature yet. they have only applied that on double tap , the root screen of that stack navigator will popup in place of the history stack

Comment: i have handler double tab with if, `if (this.props.navigation.state.index === 0) {` but i can't calling my fucntion in HomeScreen, my if is in `FooterTabs` and my function in `HomeScreen`